# Current Visible fragment in viewpager 2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2

i'm facing a small issue with fragments in viewpager 2 , so basically i want to get the current visible fragment in viewpager and then do some actions , but i tried many ways and eventually didin't succeed , if any could show me some way to do , i'd deeply appreciate it an thank you in advance .

- I tried to use currentItem but didn't do the job

```
  
  if(binding.mainViewPager.currentItem == 0){
            sharedViewModel.setQuery(newText?.toLowerCase()!!)
        } else {
            sharedViewModel.setQuery(newText?.toLowerCase()!!)
        }
```

Comment: normally it should work have you tested with Log?

Comment: or you must add the `registerPageChangeCallback`

Comment: Yeah i did pass a log to both code blocks , in position 0 , log gets called but when  i move to next fragment , it dosnt get called

Answer (score 0):

Able to get current Fragment by using custom adapter to View Pager. Call below method inside onCreate() of Activity.

```
    private fun initViewPager() {
    try {
        viewPager.adapter?.let { viewPager.adapter = null }

        val customAdapter = 
        CustomViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager).apply {
            this.addFragment(FirstFragment())
            this.addFragment(SecondFragment())
            this.addFragment(ThirdFragment())
        
            viewPager.adapter = this
        }
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
            override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {
            }
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                Log.d("log==>>","Selected Page number= $position")
                when(position) {
                    1 -> {
                        Log.d("log==>>","Current visible fragment code= 1")
                        customAdapter.updateFragmentCode(1)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
            }

        })
        //viewPager.setOnTouchListener { v, event -> true }
    } catch (error: Exception) {
        Log.d("log==>>", "Error : initViewPager()", error)
    }
}
```

I have stored fragments in my Custom Adapter class, then mapping the current fragment with the current page number which I already get from above listener. My Custom Adapter looks like :-

```
    class CustomViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager) {

    private val mFragmentList = ArrayList<Fragment>()
    private val mFragmentTitleList = ArrayList<String>()

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return mFragmentList[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return mFragmentList.size
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return mFragmentTitleList[position]
    }

    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment)
    }
    fun updateFragmentByCurrentPageNumber(fragmentNumber: Int){
        when(fragmentNumber){
            1 -> {
                (mFragmentList[1] as FirstFragment).showLog() // Can call any method inside First Fragment
            }
            2 -> {
                (mFragmentList[2] as SecondFragment).showLog() // Can call any method inside Second Fragment
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that should work , but i was morre about knowing how to get the current fragment visibility , thank you

Comment: I updated my answer. Now I am able to get the fragment itself my mapping current page number with previously stored fragment list. Please check it out and let me know.